# wso2am-analytics 2.2.0 spark on offset 0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

Installing wso2am-analytics-2.2.0 on the port offset 0, then I get error messages as

```
WARN {org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager} -  Lost task 0.0 in stage 2990.0 (TID 147439, 10.0.11.26): FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(0, someserver.compute.internal, 12001), shuffleId=745, mapId=0, reduceId=0, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to ip-10-0-17-131.eu-central-1.compute.internal:12001
```

Apparently somewhere is configured to connect to port 12001 (while seems the server listens on 12000)

Where could I configure the port 12000?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This port is defined in `<Product_Home>repository/conf/analytics/spark/spark-defaults.conf`. Property name is `spark.blockManager.port`. However you shouldn't manually configure it.

This particular issue is a connectivity problem in my knowledge. DAS uses 1200x range ports to spark executor communications. So incase of multiple executors or new executor spawning in and event of one executor getting killed incremented port will be opened. Hence at the network level also we should allow traffic through that port range. So opening that port range in your network interface `ip-10-0-17-131.eu-central-1.compute.internal` will solve your issue.